# How to view the Custom objects that are defined in Apache Ignite Cache

Tags: caching, ignite, dbeaver

How to view the Java Custom objects and their values in Apache Ignite Cache through DBeaver or any other tool. as of now, the DBeaver is able to display the Cache objects in the form of an RDBMS table for only Java defined data types

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver can show cache contents, for which [QueryEntities](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query-configuration-using-queryentity) or [indexed types](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query-configuration-by-annotations) are configured. This configuration specifies a way of conversion of Java objects into SQL tables, that can be viewed by any JDBC client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web Console's Scan Queries or REST API to view objects which don't have SQL mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer - actually you need to use `to_char("column name")` for custom objects.